# Marketing Cloud Cordova Plugin - iOS Push Notifications - entitlements required?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush, cordova

We are using Cordova for our mobile apps and hence we are in process of integrating Marketing Cloud Cordova Plugin with our cordova app. I had a question do we have to set aps-environment entitlement separately in any ios app plist to have push enabled in out app or is that not required after consuming the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

@sij the entitlement for push is set at the application level. When integrating the MobilePush SDK, you should then set the "Push Notification" capability in the Xcode target settings for your app.

This will set up your entitlements as well as your code signing/app ID settings (if you're using automatic code signing).

Depending on your application development workflow, you *may* need to set the capabilities switch for push after doing subsequent "cordova prepare" steps - we have seen cases where Cordova resets the entitlements plist.

Comment: thanks Brian, Request this to be added tothe cordova-plugin readme too.

Comment: @sij I've added a ticket for this to address in our next round of doc updates. Thank you for calling it out!